# If $A$ is a set that is at most countable, show that $\mu(A)=0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure generated by a continuous distribution function $F$. If $A$ is a set that is at most countable, show that $\mu(A)=0$.

My try:

Since $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure generated by a continuous distribution function $F$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\mu((a,b])= F(b)-F(a),~-\infty<a<b<\infty.
\end{eqnarray}

It follows from the above equation that
\begin{align}
\mu(\{b\})&=\mu\left(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(b-\frac{1}{n},b\right]\right)\\&=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}F(b)-F\left(b-\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
        &=F(b)-\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}F\left(b-\frac{1}{n}\right)\\ 
        &=F(b)-F\left(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} b-\frac{1}{n}\right) (\text{because of continuity of}~F)\\
        &=0.
\end{align}

Now, let us assume that

\begin{align}
A=\{a_{1},a_{2},\ldots\}
\end{align}

is an enumeration of the elements of $A$. Then,

\begin{align}
\mu(A)&=\mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a_{n}\}\right)\\
      &=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(\{a_{n}\}) ~(\text{follows from the countable additivity of}~\mu)\\
      &=0.
\end{align}

Is my approach correct? If not, can someone please point out the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your proof seems correct.

Comment: @HanulJeon Thank you.

Comment: You are correct. I give one question. What if distribution function $F$ is right continus?

Comment: @Planche A distribution function $F$ is always right-continuous, by definition.

Comment: @AGuyWhoWantsToSucceed I know distribution is right continuous. But You proved this property under assumption $F$ IS continuous and You used continuity of $F$. $\lim F(b-1/n) = F(b)$

Comment: \@Planche For a distribution function which is not continuous, in general, I do not know if this result holds. One could give counterexamples using the distribution function of a discrete random variable.

Comment: Seems correct. The first union should be intersection, however.

Comment: You can easily show that for any measure in which singletons have measure zero, a countable set also has measure zero by the countable additivity (as you did at the end). So you were only required to show that for a Lesbesgue-Stieljes, singletons have measure zero. Good job.

Comment: @Peter Franek thank you for pointing the error to me. It is indeed intersection.

Comment: @Mathematician 42 thank you.